# Error while running a program on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-home

Error in android while trying to start Virtual Device Manager:

```
Cannot launch AVD manager.
```

Output:

```
"C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~2\sdk\tools\lib\\find_java.exe" -s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads

If you already have Java installed, you can define the JAVA_HOME environment
variable in Control Panel / System / Avanced System Settings to point to the
JDK folder.

You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
  http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html
```

I have reinstalled java jdk several times, i have also set the `JAVA_HOME` variable correctly.
This problem also persisted in eclipse so i installed android studio.
Exact value of `JAVA_HOME` : `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\"`.

If any further detail is needed i 'll provide it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, AndroidStudio generally looks out for JRE stuff and Eclipse looks out for JDK stuff. This is what I've done to make both Eclipse and AS work in my system:

Set 2 Environment Variables like below and see if it works..It worked for me without issues

```
JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java

JDK_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
```

Hope this helps...